# What is a direct correlation?

Tags: statistics, definition, correlation

I have two contrary definitions of for the *direct correlation* between two variables $X$ and $Y$

- Their correlation coefficient is close to $1$.
- There is a direct causal relationship between the variables (ie. there is no $Z$ such that $Z$ causes $X$ and $Z$ causes $Y$)

Which one is correct?

Comment: What does $Z\to X$ mean?

Comment: I assumed that the arrow means "implies" or "causes".

Comment: @StefanHansen I wanted to say "causes" with the right arrow. Edited with plain text. Thanks for pointing out this undefined notation.

Comment: Reference for "positive correlation": [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/direct+correlation). Reference for "direct cause": [Statistique : Dictionnaire encyclopédique](http://books.google.fr/books?id=PyDEP3M-T4cC&pg=PA104&dq=corr%C3%A9lation+directe&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pB9UUe_WJoeBhQejqIHgAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=corr%C3%A9lation%20directe&f=false)

Comment: Neither of two can be  (formally, semantically) a definition of "direct correlation". At most, they could correspond to "there is a high direct correlation between X and Y". Formally. Materially, the first actually (and simply) correspond to "high correlation" (plain correlation). The second is is apt but is totally informal and matematically useless (it's rather an interpretation -and questionable-) of a probabilistic property.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a statistician (though I taught statistics about 35 years ago). But I'd say that the first definition is correct. One of the important points about correlation is that it should not be confused with causality. Remember the old joke: Smoking and cancer are correlated; does this mean that smoking causes cancer, or that cancer causes smoking. Neither one -- correlation by itself does not imply causality in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

A correlation in which large values of one variable are associated with large values of the other and small with small; the correlation coefficient is between 0 and +1. Hope this helps

Comment: Is this from [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/direct+correlation) or another source?